# Understanding asynchronous and synchronous in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

We know that in Dart everything runs synchronously and according to some definition I found on internet

**When you execute something synchronously, you wait for it to finish before moving on to another task. When you execute something asynchronously, you can move on to another task before it finishes.**

What I don't understand here is that why **b** is printed before **c** I mean if code is running synchronously then it should wait for completion of line 2 to print **c** and only after printing **c**
It should print **b**

Ps- I know I can use async and await keywords to wait for line 2 to complete it's execution. I just want to understand how this synchronous code works.

```
void main(){

   print("a");

   Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 
   5),(){
    print("c");
  });
   print("b");
}

Output- a
        b
        c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write :

```dart
print("a");

Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5),(){
    print("c");
});
print("b");
```

You tell the program to print "a", then to launch a `Future` that will resolve in 5 seconds and print "c", then to print "b"; but you never tell the program to wait for the `Future` to complete.

Which is synchronous.

And this is why you must use `await` keyword to make the program wait for the `Future` completion before moving to next instruction.

Comment: Well Explained!

Answer (score 2):

No not really. It would only print `c` before `b` if you use the `await` keyword. This keyword tells Dart to wait till this future is complete and then move on to the next task.

For example

```
void main() async {

   print("a");
//await tells dart to wait till this completes. If it's not used before a future, then dart doesn't wait till the future is completed and executes the next tasks/code.
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 
   5),(){
    print("c");
  });
   print("b");
}
```

Output

```
Output- a
        c
        b
```